# Scala object apply method never called in Spark Job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to decouple my logic in **spark** app. I created seperate class for **UDF definitions** and **UDF declarations**:

**UDF Declaration:**

```
import OPXUdfDefinitions._ 
object OPXUdf extends Serializable {
  def apply(argsInput: Map[String, String]) = {
    OPXUdfDefinitions(argsInput)
  }
  val myUDF = udf(myDef _)
}
```

**UDF Definition:**

```
object OPXUdfDefinitions extends Serializable{

  private var args: Map[String, String] = _

  def apply(argsInput: Map[String, String]) = {
    args = argsInput
    println("Inside Apply UDFDef" + args)                       // This never called
  }

  lazy val path = args.getOrElse(PATH, "/path/")               // Here is a NullPointerException
  lazy val myCustomObj = new MyClass(path)

  def myDef(a: Integer, b: Integer) = { 
    myCustomObj.getValue(util.Arrays.asList(a, b))
  }

}
```

Then I have a **class** which calls the UDF:

```
import OPXUdf._
class Tasks(args: Map[String, String]){
  def getValue()(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    df.withColumn("Value", myUDF(col("Num1"), col("Num2")))
  }
}
```

Then I have an **abstract class** for my **ETL Job** and **Definition**:

```
case class EtlDefinition(
                          sourceDF: DataFrame,
                          transform: (DataFrame => DataFrame),
                          write: (DataFrame => Unit),
                          metadata: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Any] = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Any]()
                        ) extends Serializable {

  def process(): Unit = {
    write(sourceDF.transform(transform))
  }
}

abstract class ETLJob extends Serializable{

  def read(): DataFrame
  def transform()(df: DataFrame): DataFrame
  def write()(df:DataFrame): Unit

  def execute(): Unit ={
    // Define a base ETL Job for all the usecases
    val etl = new EtlDefinition(
      sourceDF = read(),
      transform = transform(),
      write = write()
    )

    // Execute the job
    etl.process()
  }
}
```

Then I have my **ETL Job**:

```
class MyETLJob(spark: SparkSession, args: Map[String, String]) extends ETLJob {

  val files = args.getOrElse(INPUT_PATH, null).split(",")
  val outputPath = args.getOrElse(OUTPUT_PATH, null)
  override def read(): DataFrame = {
    val inputDF = spark.read.
      format("com.databricks.spark.avro").
      load(files: _*)
    inputDF
  }

  override def transform()(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val tasks = new Tasks(args)
    val transformedDF = df
      .transform(tasks.getValue())

    transformedDF
  }

  override def write()(df: DataFrame): Unit = {
    df
      .write
      .mode("overwrite")
      .parquet(outputPath)
  }
}
```

Then in my main class i am calling:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // Parse the arguments and create a map
    val argParams = ArgumentParser.parse(args)
    println("ParamsMap: " + argParams)  // I am getting the map here

    OPXUdfDefinitions(argParams)
    OPXUdf(argParams)

    val conf = new SparkConf().
      set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "100").
      set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "true")

    val spark = SparkSession.
      builder().
      appName("My App").
      config(conf).
      getOrCreate()

  val etlJob = new MyETLJob(spark, argParams)
  etlJob.execute()
}
```

But my **OPXUdfDefinitions** apply never got called and I am always getting **null pointer exception** whenever **myUDF** got called. I tried to initialized the path variable using lazy but still null pointer exception.

Here is the **stacktrace:**

```
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$myUDF$1: (int, int) => string)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.ScalaUDF_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.subExpr_3$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:217)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec$$anonfun$1.apply(SortExec.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec$$anonfun$1.apply(SortExec.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.myjob.app.OPXUdfDefinitions$.path$lzycompute(OPXUdfDefinitions.scala:37)
        at com.myjob.app.OPXUdfDefinitions$.path(OPXUdfDefinitions.scala:37)
        at com.myjob.app.OPXUdfDefinitions$.myCustomObj$lzycompute(OPXUdfDefinitions.scala:38)
        at com.myjob.app.OPXUdfDefinitions$.myCustomObj(OPXUdfDefinitions.scala:38)
        at com.myjob.app.OPXUdfDefinitions$.myDef(OPXUdfDefinitions.scala:45)
        at com.myjob.app.OPXUdf$$anonfun$myUDF$1.apply(OPXUdf.scala:19)
        at com.myjob.app.OPXUdf$$anonfun$myUDF$1.apply(OPXUdf.scala:19)
```

It would be great if someone can explain what I am doing wrong and how it can be corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside the `OPXUdfDefinitions`, because even though the `path` is `lazy`, you are calling the `args` before being initialized in the `apply` method, when calling `println("UDFDef" + args)`.

If you remove the `println(args)` you shouldn't encounter a `NullPointerException` anymore, like so:

```
object OPXUdfDefinitions extends Serializable{

  private var args: Map[String, String] = _

  def apply(argsInput: Map[String, String]) = {
    args = argsInput
    println("Inside Apply UDFDef" + args)                       // This never called
  }

  //println("UDFDef" + args)   // this is initializing args
  lazy val path = args.getOrElse(PATH, "/path/")
  lazy val myCustomObj = new MyClass(path)
  //println("UDFDef" + args)    // same here

  def myDef(a: Integer, b: Integer) = { 
    myCustomObj.getValue(util.Arrays.asList(a, b))
  }

}
```

Comment: I tried that as well. But it didn't work. This program runs fine on my loval machine, but not on AWS EMR.

Comment: You should post the stacktrace after removing the `println(args)`, because I'm sure that at least the error comes from another place and gives more information about the actual problem.

Comment: I have the println just to mark where Im getting the null pointer exception.

Comment: Yes, but that breaks the code, like I said in my answer. It will be null because `path` is using `args` (i'm talking about the `println("UDFDef" + args)` above `lazy val path = ...`) before being initialized, when the `OPXUdfDefinitions` object is created. It will be more helpful to the NPE under normal running of the program. I will edit the answer to show how it should look like for better debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try?:

```
def myDef(a: Integer, b: Integer): String = {
```

and

```
val myUDF = udf((a: Integer, b: Integer) => myDef(a,b))
```

Comment: Why would it have a effect?

Comment: Some times `Spark` with `Scala` has problems with the types, An obvious `String` becomes `Any` and doesn't work in the execution, but compiles correctly. I tested parts of your code and it worked, so I thought that should be the problem.